# Custom password Winform

Tags: c#, dialog

I am working on a c# winform application and i have a button that on click a dialog asking for password appears. If the password is correct then the code under the button is executed. Here is the code on the main form.

```
    password pass = new password();
       pass.ShowDialog();
      if (pass.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (pass.Password == "12")
            {
```

And below is the code that i have on the OK button in the password form

```
      private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

The problem is that the OK button of the password form has to be clicked twice and is working. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Can you show the code of your `password` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Button.DialogResult documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) I see that the property defines what DialogResult to return to the Form **when the button is clicked**. This means you should have the code line `button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` in the constructor, or simply set it in the designer, instead of on the click-event.

Answer (score 3):

Set the AcceptButton property of the dialog form to the OK button, and remove the btnOK_click event.

Comment: @user1292656 because you are handled its `Click` event. remove event handler and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Call `this.Close(...)` inside `btnOK_Click`

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but the point is when i click the Ok the dialogresult is set automatically to Cancel instead of OK

Answer (score 0):

Set the AcceptButton of the password form to the btnOK. And remove the click event handler. You don't require an event handler - From documentation - If the DialogResult for this property is set to anything other than None, and **if the parent form was displayed through the ShowDialog method, clicking the button closes the parent form without your having to hook up any events**. The form's DialogResult property is then set to the DialogResult of the button when the button is clicked.

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx